# How to remove "Licence product key" in Visulal studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

## How to remove Visual studio 2015 Licence Product Key.

if  it is possible in "command prompt" Codes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Go to Run->regedit
Open register editor 
**Step2:**
and choose Path 
"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Licenses"
**Step3:**
Delete the key

Comment: In that case `reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Licenses` should do it from the commandline.